# react context api to replace redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I want to ditch redux since context API in react 16.8 is solving the prop drilling pain. But one thing I'll lose is now I have to do calls whenever I click back. In redux, we know we can easily call the store for data instead of doing another new HTTP call again. Redux handle it for us.

Anyone know which mini lib to have this benefit?

Comment: Redux solves far more than prop drilling, it is an event store with all of the benifits that you get from event sourcing. In short; it decouples a thing that happened (action) with what the application needs to do when it happens (middle ware and reducers). Redux is a tool that can make it easier to implement complex requirements but if your application does not have complex requirements than maybe context would be enough. If you want to cache rest api results then why not implement it in service worker, that's what it's for.

Comment: redux is overrated after context api and hook came out, many chose to ditch it. if your app is big, redux make ur bundle big. I'm thinking, is It time to leave it or to find alternative.